# How do I get computed styles from browser's dev tools?

Tags: javascript, css, web-developer-toolbar, getcomputedstyle

I'm collecting all computed styles of an element with getComputedStyle. But it returns many unnecessary properties like 'animation-duration', 'direction', 'ime-mode', etc, yielding more than 200 properties total. Meanwhile browser's web dev toolbar shows only relevant computed styles. How do I access them?

Edit: Sorry, the question might be a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19648164/javascript-getcomputedstyle-but-not-inherited-ones-in-chrome) (though the latter seems to be about Google Chrome specifically).

Comment: Are you okay with using jquery and related plugins for this purpose?

Comment: @Kamlesh, sure, I am.

Comment: Try this : http://addyosmani.com/blog/autosave-changes-chrome-dev-tools/